# Retrieving single image from the internet using multiple threads

Tags: android, multithreading, http

I have an android application which is required to download huge size images from the server. Currently downloading takes very long time even if i used sampling since sampling only save memory but in all cases the whole image should be fetched from the server. So, I need to know how can I create multiple threads to download chunks of a single resource and reorder those chunks again to restore the image. I think I should use the http headers to control this but I don't know how and would appreciate if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading won't increase your bandwidth. Your download is bottlenecked by your network speed, not your processor speed. Multithreading won't help you.

Depending on the situation, you could try caching the image, using smaller or lower res images, packaging the image in the app, etc.

Comment: Disagree. The slowliness is because downloading the image happens in a single thread.  Internet download manager for instance uses multiple threads to download a resource and thats why it's downloading faster